# Geometric Distribution within a Normal Distribution

Tags: probability, statistics

So here's the problem:

On Interstate 40 north of Chapel Hill, the distribution of speeds of cars is approximately normal with mean 60.6 miles/hour with standard deviation equal to 4.78 miles/hour. We assume that the speeds of individual cars on the highway are independent of each other (you may want to consider why this is an erroneous assumption!)
The speed limit on this stretch of I-40 is 65 miles/hour.

(a) A highway patrol officer is hidden on the side of the highway. What is the probability that the next 5 cars that pass are traveling at a lawful speed? (Give each answer to three decimal places.)

I assumed that p would be .68 since 68% of the data lie within 1 standard deviation in a normal distribution. To answer a, I did (.68 * 5), which came out to be 3.400 but this is incorrect.

How do I determine the probability that a car is traveling within the normal speed limit? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, in the first place, the speed limit is not quite $1$ standard deviation above the mean.  It's $4.4$ mph above the mean, which works out to $4.4/4.78 \doteq 0.92$ standard deviations.  So, use your $z$-table, your symbolic calculator, the web—whatever—to find the probability $p$ that a normally distributed random variable is "to the left" of $0.92$ standard deviations above the mean.  (For instance, it can be arbitrarily less than the mean; it doesn't have to be less than $1$ standard deviation *below* the mean.)

Secondly, if the probability that a single car is below the speed limit is $p$, the probability that five cars are each below the speed limit isn't $5p$ (unless $p = 0$).  Probabilities have to be between $0$ and $1$; they can't be something as high as $3.4$.

Instead, once you have determined this $p$, which should be somewhere in the range $0.8$ to $0.9$, the probability that two cars are *both* below the speed limit, assuming that the speeds are independent*, is $p$ times $p$, or $p^2$.  The probability that three cars are each below the speed limit is $p$ times $p$ times $p$, or $p^3$.  So the probability that five cars are all under the speed limit is $\ldots$

*Of course, in practice, because cars follow each other, the speeds aren't independent.  But in these kinds of textbook problems, we tend to ignore such complications.

ETA: There is an example of such a table here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_normal_table#Cumulative

Read the rest of the article to understand how to use it.  Be sure to use the Cumulative table (less than $z$, not between $0$ and $z$).

Comment: Using excel, would finding p be norm.dist(.92, 60.6, 4.78, true)?

Comment: No.  Why are you mixing units between standard deviations and mph?  Didn't you try it and notice that you got a ridiculously small probability for $p$?  You can do either NORM.DIST(65, 60.6, 4.78, true) using mph, or NORM.DIST(0.92, 0, 1, true) using standard deviations.  These won't be exactly equal, because 65 mph isn't exactly 0.92 standard deviations above 60.6 mph.  So the more accurate answer would be obtained by using the first formulation.

Comment: Oh, ok. I just used the table. Thanks!